# How to join two tables in a one-to-many relation, and keep only one-to-one records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables : `Folders` and `References`. A folder can have 0 to 2 references (usually 1 or 2).

I have an existing query that search `Folders` that respect certains conditions. The query must have a new condition : Find only `Folders` with one reference.

*Ideally*, to limits change to this old application, the new condition should be within the `WHERE` clause only (This rule out `group by x, having y`).

Ex :

```
FolderId Name
0        Folder0
1        Folder1
2        Folder2

RefId FolderId Name
0     1        ref1
1     2        ref2
2     2        ref3
```

The output should only contain the FolderId **1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
select . . .
from folders f join
     (select r.*, count(*) over (partition by folderid) as cnt
      from references r
     ) r
     on f.folderid = r.folderid and cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the query below to create a temporary table or create a table variable:

```
create table #Temp
(
    column_name int
)

insert into #Temp
     SELECT column_name
      FROM table_name
     GROUP BY column_name
    HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 1;
```

Then use the temp table with `join` to other tables and place the conditions you want.

Comment: it's a good simple answer without that extra temp table stuff.